# Small messages are not received immediately with WebSphere MQ MQGMO_BROWSE

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

We are using IBM WebSphere MQ to implement simple pub/sub, with one writer putting binary protobuf messages on a queue and multiple readers browsing it. All readers are browsing (there are no destructive gets) so the messages are set to expire after 10 seconds.

We are experiencing an issue messages using the .NET MQ client library, where very small messages seem to be buffered and received in a batch, rather than being received immediately as soon as they are put on the queue.

We are calling `Get()` with `MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQGMO_WAIT | MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST/NEXT` and `WaitInterval = MQWI_UNLIMITED`. With these flags, `Get()` blocks indefinitely until returning the next available message.

When the messages are larger than 4KB, an unlimited blocking get behaves as expected and returns as soon as a message is available:

```
    Sender  |  Reader     
------------+------------
            | get        
 put msg #1 |            
            | <-- msg #1 
            | get        
 put msg #2 |            
            | <-- msg #2 
            | get        
 put msg #3 |            
            | <-- msg #3
```

However when the messages are small (approx 130 bytes in our case), then get doesn't return until two or three messages are available:

```
    Sender  |  Reader     
------------+------------
            | get        
 put msg #1 |            
 put msg #2 |            
 put msg #3 |            
            | <-- msg #1 
            | get        
            | <-- msg #2 
            | get        
            | <-- msg #3
```

The messages appear immediately in AppWatch, and are received immediately if we change from browse to destructive get. So we know it's a problem with the reader and browsing.

We have identified three workarounds but they are not optimal:

1. Pad messages to ensure they are always larger than 4KB
2. Instead of `MQWI_UNLIMITED`, call `Get()` in a loop with `WaitInterval` = e.g. 10s. This means individual messages will be received , but they will be up to 10s late.
3. Switch to destructive read instead of browse. But this means we would need a dedicated queue per reader.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: Why are you browsing instead of get (destructive). I fail to understand the reason behind it.  In general, MQ applications use get() to take the message off the queue nullifying the need to expire messages.  The queue buffers are optimized for put/get not for browse.  If you are afraid of losing messages then they can be get() under a syncpoint.

Comment: The size of the message shouldn't make any difference to the getter. Have you ruled out a problem with the putter by using a known working get program such as the sample amqsget or amqsbcg (browse)?

Comment: @Umapathy: we are using put + browse to implement simple fanout pub/sub. It's not the ideal technology choice but we needed a quick solution with existing infrastructure.

Comment: @MoragHughson We ruled out a problem with the putter because we can see the messages immediately in AppWatch.

Comment: Why aren't you using the pub/sub infrastructure provided by MQ?

Comment: Keep in mind that this would not be an issue using the native MQ Pub/Sub.  Any time that native functionality is simulated by torturing some other functionality, it's just asking for trouble. All that notwithstanding I have to ask - are the messages of a different priority?  This sounds like a case of messages arriving logically ahead of the current browse cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

If the sender and receiver application are connected to a different queue manager, and the queue managers are connected via a channel, then this can be fixed by amending the BATCHLIM attribute of the channel:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q114230_.htm

Channels transfer messages in batches, and until a batch is not committed, the messages transferred in that batch are not available for get. Batches are committed when either the number of messages, the size of the transferred messages or the time interval of the batch being open reach the threshold set on the channel.

Comment: In this case the sender and receiver are connected to the same queue manager.